# How to implement ckrefreshcontrol to support ios5?

Tags: xcode, ios5, github, uirefreshcontrol

I've seen in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085045/objective-c-add-support-for-new-classes-to-old-devices) that CKRefreshControl can be used as a substitute for UIRefreshControl for apps that support both iOS5 and iOS6.  I've found the code on [Github](https://github.com/instructure/CKRefreshControl), but I don't know how to implement it.  [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1984416/john-haitas) said to just use the same code.  But something is missing.  Where does the CKRefreshControl code go?

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the README.md on the GitHub page you linked to? https://github.com/instructure/CKRefreshControl/blob/master/README.md

Comment: That GitHub repository also provides a clear example of how to use the control: https://github.com/instructure/CKRefreshControl/blob/master/RefreshControlDemo/DefaultRefreshController.m
If you don't understand how to set up the library code in the project, download the entire repository and open the demo Xcode project to see how it's linked in.

Comment: I feel a little stupid and lazy. I did indeed read the README. It says no more than John did. Just use the UIRefreshControl line, as usual. Huh?  I've set up library code in a number of other projects. But I can't see "a library" for this to add.  I really didn't want to go through downloading, installing and scrutinizing the entire repository when it seems like there SHOULD be a simple answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific `CKRefreshControl` code needed other than the CKRefreshControl source itself. When `CKRefreshControl` was first released you had to replace all calls to `UIRefreshControl` with calls to `CKRefreshControl`, and then it automatically dispatched to the correct class based on whether you were on iOS 5 or on iOS 6+.

However, with the recent contributions from [John Haitas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1984416/john-haitas), that is no longer necessary. Instead, simply compiling and linking against the CKRefreshControl source code makes the `UIRefreshControl` class available when targeting iOS 5. As a result, you can simply continue to use `[[UIRefreshControl alloc] init]`, and it will automatically work on iOS 5.

Why should you believe me? Because I'm the guy who wrote `CKRefreshControl` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

1)  Add the 3 classes and prefix to your project:

```
 - CKParagraphStyle.h  and  CKParagraphStyle.m
 - CKParagraphStyle.h  and  CKRefreshArrowView.m
 - CKRefreshControl.h  and  CKRefreshControl.m
 - CKRefreshControl-Prefix.pch  (goes into TableVCs using Refresh).
```

2)  Add the QuartzCore.framework to the target libraries.

3)  Add this method:

```
-(void)doRefresh:(CKRefreshControl *)sender {
        NSLog(@"refreshing");
        [self.refreshControl performSelector:@selector(endRefreshing) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    }
```

Finally, use UIRefreshControl, as usual, but select the doRefresh method:

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(doRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```